# Demographic Info within 3 miles of longitude and latitude

Tags: arcmap, geocoding, business, census

I want to get demographic information within three or five miles of a location given its longitude and latitude. The demographic info I am looking for include number of people, age distribution, income distribution, race distribution etc...

Answer (score 4):

1. [Download tiger census block shapefile for your area of interest](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles2010/main).
2. [Download American Fact Finder demographic tables to join to your block shapefile](http://factfinder2.census.gov/main.html).
3. Create a point shapefile for your long/lat coordinates.
4. You can then use the Select by Location option to select block features within your buffer distance for each point feature.
5. Summarize selected features by demographic field values.